# as3 dynamically loaded font undefined fontname

Tags: actionscript-3, format, undefined, textfield, textformat

I have a font I want to apply to a TextField, but before I could do that, it threw an undefined error. Here is my code:

```
var tFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
trace(NumberFont);
```

which traces `[class NumberFont]` without problems, but I understand that I need a String, not a class to set the TextField font.

When I try to get the name:
    `trace(NumberFont.fontName);`

it gives a compiler error

`1119: Access of possibly undefined property fontName through a reference with static type Class.`

The code seems basic, but I am totally unfamiliar with TextFormat. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should instantiate the font and access the fontName instance property:

```
var font:NumberFont = new NumberFont();
var tFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat(font.fontName);
```

Comment: Of course! I have to access an object rather than class. It doesn't throw an error, but it still doesn't show the text in a different font.